# How to modify outer scope of a function in python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def sum(x):
   result = 0
   def inner(x = None):
     if x == None:
       return result
     else:
       result = result + x
       return inner
   return inner(x)

sum(10)(20)(20)()
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
    sum(10)(20)(20)()
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in sum
    return inner(x)
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in inner
    result = result + x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

I can use `global` to use variable that is in global scope but how can I use the one that is in scope one level up?

if I remove the line `result = result + x` it return 0 so it see the variable but it can't modify it.

Comment: you are looking for `nonlocal`, use it instead of `global`

Comment: @Sraw this is exactly what I need, thanks, you can add this as an answer.